# Have I just found a bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have written simple page with fixed sidebar and footer. Sidebar is child of a div located outside the window, just to the right of it. Sidebar should always be behind footer. Everything works fine on Firefox, Edge and Opera but on Chrome sidebar is sometimes on top and sometimes behind footer. When page is loaded and you scroll to bottom sidebar is on top (incorrectly). Then when action is performed on sidebar (for example mouse hovers over inputbox located on sidebar) sidebar is sent back and Chrome displays page correctly. If you would scroll to top (to make footer invisible) and hover mouse over inputbox again, Chrome goes back to displaying sidebar on top.
Here is codepen demonstrating this: [codePen](https://codepen.io/encePence/pen/bGeJBWo)

And here is code:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 160vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
input{font-size:2vw;}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#sideAnchor {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}
#side {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
#side input:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideAnchor">
    <div id="side">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Hover over this" /><br />
        This should always be behind footer
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   This should always be on top
</div>
```

I have a workaround this so I'm not asking for solution. In my opinion there is a bug in Chrome, what do you think? I'm using Google Chrome 87.0.4280.66, Windows 10

Comment: Have a read around stacking orders here: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: This doesn't explain why behaviour is different in Chrome and in other browsers, also why sidebar goes on top and behind footer depending on other actions

Comment: Have a read. `position: fixed;` will create a new stacking context and how browser implemented this is different but not a bug as it's not been defined in the specs (unless it has been at which point its one of the 34873745 bugs) ;)

Comment: So yeah, it's a bug. Rendering bugs are not that uncommon in Chrome. They often get fixed quite quickly and as it happens in Chrome Canary (v89) it seems to be already fixed.